# Find the solutions for $y''+y= \sin(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having a bit of confusion in finding the solutions to the second order differential equation: $$y''+y= \sin(x)$$
We have been told that the homogeneous solution is $0$

To find the particular solution this is what I have done so far:

$$y_p=A \sin(x)+B \cos(x)$$
$$y''_p=-A \sin(x)-B \cos(x)$$
Therefore

$$-A \sin(x)-B \cos(x)+A \sin(x)+B \cos(x)= \sin(x)$$
thus
$$0= \sin(x)$$

Does this mean that the general solution is $y=0?$

Comment: I think you mean y''+y = sin(x)

Comment: If the form of the particular solution has terms that are already part of the homogeneous solution, then you need to multiply $y_p$ by $t$.  Use $y_p = At\sin t +B t \cos t$.  (The $t$ comes from using reduction of order in the "annihilator method."

Comment: Fyi if you put a backslash "\" before trig functions and logs it formats them as $\sin \theta$ instead of $sin \theta$, and $\ln x$ instead of $ln x$

Comment: @B.Goddard does that mean $y''_p = -Atcost-Btsint$?

Comment: @user375681  No.  You have to use product rule.  The derivatives get pretty long.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{z = y' + y\ic\implies z' = y'' + y'\ic\implies \color{#f00}{y'' + y} =
> \pars{z' - y'\ic} + \pars{-z\ic + y'\ic} = \color{#f00}{z' - z\ic}}$
>   
>   and $\bbox[8px,border:0.1em groove navy]{\ds{y = \Im\pars{z}}}$

\begin{align}
&z' - z\ic  = \sin\pars{x} \implies
\totald{\pars{\expo{-\ic x}z}}{x} = \expo{-\ic x}\sin\pars{x} =
-\,{\ic \over 2}\pars{1 - \expo{-2\ic x}}
\\[5mm] &
\expo{-\ic x}z = -\,{\ic \over 2}\,x + {\ic \over 2}{\expo{-2\ic x} \over -2\ic} + C\,,\qquad C = constant\ \in\ \mathbb{C}
\\[5mm] &
z =  -\,{\ic \over 2}\,x\expo{\ic x} - {1 \over 4}\,\expo{-\ic x} + C\expo{\ic x}
\implies
\color{#f00}{\mrm{y}\pars{x}} = \Im\pars{z} =
\color{#f00}{-\,{1 \over 2}\,x\cos\pars{x} + {1 \over 4}\,\sin\pars{x} +
\Im\pars{C\expo{\ic x}}}
\end{align}

> As $\bbox[4px,#ddd]{\texttt{@Jack Lam}}$ observed, the term
>   $\ds{{1 \over 4}\,\sin\pars{x}}$ can be absorbed into the last term. It's equivalent to:

$$
\color{#f00}{\mrm{y}\pars{x}} = \Im\pars{z} =
\color{#f00}{-\,{1 \over 2}\,x\cos\pars{x} +  a\sin\pars{x} + b\cos\pars{x}}\,,
\qquad a, b \in \mathbb{R}
$$

> $\ds{C\ \mbox{and/or}\ \pars{~a\ \mbox{and}\ b~}}$ are determined once we know some initial conditions.

Comment: the $\frac{\sin{x}}{4}$ can be absorbed into the constant amplitude harmonic., so the solution can be simplified further...

Comment: @JackLam Thanks for your remark. That's true. I left further details to the OP. I included your point of view in my answer.